# Puppet Bolt multilevel inventory yamls

Tags: puppet, puppet-bolt

From the documentation of puppet bolt and their inventory.yaml, [here](https://www.puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/inventory_files.html), it seems you can define multiple levels of the yaml file by specifying another `group` in the definition of a`group`. Thus creating a multilevel or nested inventory file.

However I can't find any examples of how to call the nested inventory files with the `bolt`  command from cli.

For instance this yaml from the docmentation:

```
groups:
  - name: ssh_nodes
    groups:
      - name: webservers
        targets:
          - 192.168.100.179
          - 192.168.100.180
          - 192.168.100.181
      - name: memcached
        targets:
          - 192.168.101.50
          - 192.168.101.60
        config:
          ssh:
            user: root
    config:
      transport: ssh
      ssh:
        user: centos
        private-key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        host-key-check: false
```

How do I call from the ssh_nodes group the `webservers` group?
Normally I use something like this to call a top level group, which in this case the `ssh_nodes` group.

```
bolt plan run "deploy::update_package" \
            --targets "ssh_nodes" \
            --user "${BOLT_USER}" \
            --private-key "${KEY}" \
            --modulepath "path/to/module" \
            --inventoryfile "${INVENTORY_FILE}" \
            package_name="${PACKAGE}" \
            package_version="${VERSION}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nesting groups is supported. All groups must be uniquely named, irrespective of nesting.

For example, if your inventory looked like this:

```yaml
groups:
  - name: dc1
    groups:
      - name: webservers
        targets:
          - 192.168.100.179
          - 192.168.100.180
          - 192.168.100.181
  - name: dc2
    groups:
      - name: webservers
        targets:
          - 192.168.101.50
          - 192.168.101.60
```

Then you attempted to view the inventory, you will get the error:

> Tried to redefine group physical for group at ["webservers", "dc2", "all"]

To get around this, I suggest prefixing nested groups like so:

```yaml
groups:
  - name: dc1
    groups:
      - name: dc1/webservers
        targets:
          - 192.168.100.179
          - 192.168.100.180
          - 192.168.100.181
  - name: dc2
    groups:
      - name: dc2/webservers
        targets:
          - 192.168.101.50
          - 192.168.101.60
```

Then you can target the groups:

```
bolt inventory show -t dc2/webservers
```